# How to efficiently copy a row in Tensorflow C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow

How can I efficiently duplicate a row many times in a C++ `tensorflow::Tensor`?

In Eigen I can do something like `M.row(1) = M.row(0)` but Tensors don't seem to have the `.row` function.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can do slicing and assignment with `chip`:

`M.chip(1, 0) = M.chip(0, 0)`